# s3 rate limit against website endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, benchmarking, throttling

I'm hitting my s3 bucket via its website endpoint with various paths/keys. I'm able to get ok (200) responses when I'm hitting it at 1,000 requests per second over the course of 5 minutes. I'm using a popular tool: https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta so I have confidence in these stats.

This is suprising considering the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) says that anything above is 800 per second is problematic.

Is using a website endpoint different than an API call in terms of throttling? Is 800 a real rate limit or a crude theshhold?

Answer (score 2):

It's a soft limit, and not really a limit from the bucket level perspective. Read carefully.  The documentation warns of a *rapid request rate increase* beyond 800 requests per second potentially resulting in *temporary rate limits on your request rate*.

S3 increases available capacity by keyspace partition splitting and it takes some time for this to happen... but buckets scale up with workload.

If you are requesting the same object(s) repeatedly, you are also not likely to be imposing as much load on the available resources as you would be if you were hitting 800 unique objects per second and reading between the lines, that is the threshold under discussion -- the time to look up keys in the bucket index.  Recent hits are probably already more accessible than cold spots in the index.

The problem that document highlights is that of your object keys are lexically sequential, then S3 will be unable to split the partitions meaningfully, because you will always be creating new objects on only one side of the split or the other and thus working against the scaling algorithm of S3.

Comment: @PavanRao I will need to update this answer.  In mid-2018, AWS rescinded this recommendation due to improvements in S3.  The new value is 5,500 GET req/sec per prefix although prefix has not been clearly defined and does not mean quite what it sounds like it would.  Each bucket has at least one, though, so 5500 is the new baseline and S3 can add more capacity to a bucket, automatically and without charge... https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has been updated in meantime and the limits have been increased. Now the limits are per bucket prefix and 1000 req/s isn't a problem any more. For more see the mentioned [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html).